# How to add textbox array value to string array?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

How to add textbox[] value to string[]

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] text = new string[DT.Columns.Count];
    string[] textb = new string[panel1.Controls.Count];

    // Below is the programmatically textbox

    foreach (Control C in panel1.Controls)
    {
        if (C is TextBox)
        {
            for (int m = 0; m < DT.Columns.Count; m++)
            {

                // This is the place that I want to add the textbox value to string array

                textb[m] = C.Text[m].ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(textb[m]);
            }
        }
    }

    foreach (DataColumn DC in DT.Columns)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < DT.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            text[k] = DC.Table.Columns[k].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy to achieve with [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/). You can just use:

```
string[] textb = panel1.Controls
                       .OfType<TextBox>()
                       .Select(t => t.Text)
                       .ToArray();
```

Comment: Explaining *why* this solution works is also just as important.

Comment: @RoadRunner I added a link to LINQ's docs. The code is self-explanatory if the OP is familiar with LINQ.